# How to debug "Undefined variable" in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

> Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\quizzer\add.php on line 67
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in >C:\xampp\htdocs\quizzer\add.php on line 67

Here's my code which is giving error:

```
$questions = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
$total = $questions->num_rows;
$next = $total+1;
```

Comment: mysql connection missing

Comment: have you set  the $query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: The error message is crystal clear. What is it you don't understand in that? You call a member function `$mysqli->query()`, right? The message says you called it on something with value `null`, so on nothing, right? If `$mysqli` is nothing, then how should that work?

Comment: $query = " SELECT * FROM 'questions'";

Comment: @AkmaljonUsmonov If you didn't used the [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) class, why are you trying to do it with `$mysqli`? you can do this: `$mysqli = new mysqli(host, user, pass, db)`.

Comment: `$con` is different from `$mysqli`...

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you didn't set `$mysqli`.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(host, user, pass, db);
```

(Replace `host`, `user`, `pass` and `db` with your database values, e.g: `localhost`, `root`, `root`, `example_db`)

[Learn more about MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) on PHP Documentation

Comment: No, `$mysqli` is _not_ a class_! It is an object that has been instantiated on the class `mysqli`. You seem to confuse the terms "class" and "object".

Comment: @arkascha I know that variable is not a class. `new mysqli`, that's where I call the class...

Comment: But that is not what you wrote, sorry. Anyway, you changed your wording to something very generic now, so all is fine. That is why I upvoted.

Comment: @arkascha Thanks. About my wording: I apologize If I had any misspelling(s). please feel free to correct me / update my answer. :-)

Comment: All fine, have fun!

Answer (score 2):

1) Connection missing

2) Remove single quotes around table name .

3) use Prepared statement

note : if we need to access the connection variable inside any function means .we can access it using that global variable.

```
//db connection

     global $conn;

        $servername = "localhost";  //host name

        $username = "username"; //username

        $password = "password"; //password

        $mysql_database = "dbname"; //database name

    //mysqli prepared statement 

        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

       mysqli_select_db($conn,$mysql_database) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");

       $query = "SELECT * FROM questions";

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
        $get_result =$stmt->get_result();

        $row_count= $get_result->num_rows;

        if($row_count>0)
        {

           while($row=$get_result->fetch_assoc())
           {

             print_r($row);
           }

        }
```

Comment: This uses a confusing mix of object-oriented style, which is preferred, and the needlessly verbose procedural methods.

Comment: can you tell me your mail please guys, i ll send the whole code. anyway it is not working. my gmail Ausmonov24@gmail.com

Comment: NOT WORKING means where your facing issue ?

Comment: I don't think the `global $conn` will only work in a function or method context (or if it does, it should nevertheless be removed - the dangers of copy and paste programming!). Will undownvote if that is removed.

Comment: @Akmaljon: please do not ask for private support here. The whole point of helping on the internet is to make the assistance public so the material written is useful for future readers as well. Volunteers rarely have time for free debugging sessions anyway, which can balloon into hours worth of work. If you need private support, consider hiring a freelancer from AirPair or TopTal.

Comment: it's not copy paste . if we need to acess the connection variable inside any function means ..we can access it using that global variable @halfer

Comment: Yes, but it is not inside a function, and beginners will copy that `global` line needlessly, since you have not explained that it should go inside a function.

Comment: @Akmaljon: please do not post large amounts of code in comments either. If you have a new problem, please ask a new question. However, there is much value in your working through the bugs that you have, one by one - and of course read the error messages to see what PHP is wanting to tell you.

Comment: if my answer is useful mark it with green tick its useful for future user reference @AkmaljonUsmonov